# Entityframework MigrationBuilder.InsertData Error after Upgrading to .NET 5

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have an application previously running .NET Core 3.xx which is now being upgraded to .NET 5.

The application is running `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 5.0.7`

We have a large amount of data which is seeded through the EF Migrations `Up` method. This work previously but since moving over to .NET 5 we get the following error message;

> There is no property mapped to the column 'Documents.AgreementId' used in a data operation. Either add a property mapped to this column or specify the column types in the data operation.

In this we associate a `Document` entity to an `Agreement` entity via a foreign key.

The `Agreement` entity is as follows;

```
public class Agreement : AuditableEntity
{
    /* removed for brevity */

    public List<Document> Documents { get; set; }
}
```

The `Document` Entity then is simply;

```
public class Document : Entity
{
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public int FileSize { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

So, the `AgreementId` FK is not listed in the `Document` Entity.

In the `Up` method we then Insert and assocaite a number of Documents as follows;

```
 migrationBuilder.InsertData(
     table: "Documents",
     columns: new[] {
         "Id",
         "Url",
         "AgreementId",
         "FileSize"
     },
     values: new object[,]
     {
          {
              fileIdCount,
              updatedLocation.Trim(),
              agreementIdCount,
              0                              
          }
      });
```

Where `AgreementId` is the confirmed FK in the database.

I have tried adding the following to the `Document` entity to fix the issue;

```
    public int? AgreementId { get; set; }
    public Agreement Agreement { get; set; }
```

here is a screen of the `Document` table in the database through Visual Studio 2019 SQL Object Explorer

[image: Object Explorer Screenshot]

I have tried running the `add-migration` command after adding the fields to the `Document` entity and it is generating no table alterations.

Does anyone have any idea on how to fix this please?

Answer (score -1):

In Document entity change AgreementId from nullable to not null.

```
public int AgreementId { get; set; }
```

Comment: you must define default value for null value in agreement table and set its id as null value for fk in document.

Comment: To update I tested this change and it made now difference. I wonder if i need to clear this seed up method, run and run a new migration prior to running thr seed?